# How to create a "Change background colour option" across multiple windows in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

New to java and javafx and I've been coding a gui and I've been trying to find a way to create a button on my option windows that will change the background colour of all the windows. I'm currently unsure of how to go about it.

In the main class I initialize the following string and make it global:

```
public static String background;
```

In the options class I have the colorpicker and then convert the hex values to a string

```
        colorPicker.setLayoutX(15.0);
        colorPicker.setLayoutY(184.0);

        // 8 symbols.
        String hex1 = Integer.toHexString(colorPicker.getValue().hashCode()); 
        // With # prefix.
        String hex2 = "#" + Integer.toHexString(colorPicker.getValue().hashCode()); 
        // 6 symbols in capital letters.
        String hex3 = Integer.toHexString(colorPicker.getValue().hashCode()).substring(0, 6).toUpperCase();
        background.equals(hex1+hex2+hex3);
```

This line of code is on every class/window to change the background colour.

```
        //sets background of current stage
        backgroundpane.styleProperty().set("-fx-background-color: "+background);
```

However when I do this I get this error: `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException` which points to the `background.equals(hex1+hex2+hex3);`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the background string to an empty string when declaring it to ensure it's never null.

```
public static String background = "";
```

That said, I think you want to assign the new background to the variable, not checking whether its already picked. So, if that's right you should replace `background.equals(hex1+hex2+hex3);` with:

```
background = hex1+hex2+hex3;
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I'm wondering whether it was something to do with the hex to string part of the code

Comment: Hmmm. I guess you need to do some debugging so you can pinpoint the exact problem. It could be the hexes as you said, I didn't think so though.

Answer (score 0):

Your hex string is incomplete, you want the 6 hex characters but since you are prepending the '#' character, you are only getting 5 of those characters. Adjust your substring to substring(0, 7)

Also you do not need to call colorpicker.getValue anymore after the first call since it is stored in the hex1 variable.

Make sure you are updating the main classes static background property properly, so instead of background.equals (which is only comparing background to something, not assigning value!), instead use MainApp.background = hex3
(MainApp being wherever you static property lives)

Also make sure your static background value is initialized with a valid hex string.